# How to split a list output (in 2 columns assigned with a condition) into two separate columns and adding it back to data frame?

Tags: r, list, syntax

I wanted to obtain MAD(mean absolute deviations) for each participant's response time and create a new column of MAD values in the data frame by adding it with rbind by participant.

I tried:

`(aggregate(df$RT, list(df$ParticipantID), FUN=mad))`
Which gave me a list

```
           Group.1         x
1            ADVIK 0.1730088
2        ANUPRABHA 0.1433658
3          ARCHANA 0.1381635
4          ARNIMAA 0.1786956
5           BHUVAN 0.1943341
6           DARANI 0.2913754
.           .      .
.           .      .
.           .      .
```

so on...

I want to separate this list and add only the mad value "x" column in the list to a data frame. How to add only the "x" values in the list to my data frame?

I'm expecting this output:

```
       Participants  RTs      MadRTs
1            ADVIK 0.9903  0.1730088
2            ADVIK 0.9563  0.1730088
3            ADVIK 0.3987  0.1730088
4            ADVIK 0.4673  0.1730088
5        ANUPRABHA 0.6574  0.1433658
6        ANUPRABHA 0.7895  0.1433658
7        ANUPRABHA 0.6587  0.1433658
8        ANUPRABHA 0.5432  0.1433658
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in base R you could do:

```
merge(df, aggregate(cbind(MadRTs = RTs) ~ Participants, df, mad))
```

in tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
  mutate(MadRTs = mad(RTs), .by = Participants)
```

older version dplyr

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    group_by(Participants) %>%
    mutate(MadRTs = mad(RTs))
```